# Selecting data from mysql table where date is current

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am getting data from MySQL table using current date but it shows zero rows

My Table Structure is

```
ActivityTypeID  int(11)         No      auto_increment                          
ActivityTypeCode    varchar(20) utf8_general_ci     No                                  
ActivityTypeDescription varchar(250)    utf8_general_ci     No                                  
UserName    varchar(50) utf8_general_ci     No                                  
AddedDateTime    date
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ActivityTypeLookup` 
WHERE AddedDateTime=CURDATE()
```

Data in Table is like below

Date is given like this but when i run this query in sql it show zero records

```
2013-06-28
```

Here is the out put

```
5       Video   You have uploaded Video to catalog  imran.husain    2013-06-28
6   Video   You have Played Video workin            imran.husain     2013-06-28
```

Comment: Are the values in AddedDateTime date only, or does it have time too?

Comment: Try using `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE()`?

Comment: it has date only not the time

Comment: @hjpotter92 NOW() also does not show any record

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM \`ActivityTypeLookup\` ORDER BY AddedDateTime DESC` give you?

Comment: @hjpotter92 it shows two records of same date

Comment: use `date(AddedDateTime)=date(CURDATE())`

Comment: @BhavikShah it also shows zero rows

Comment: Can you paste the output from my query in your question?

Comment: @hjpotter92 i have added out put of your querry in question please chcek it

Comment: What does the query `SELECT CURDATE()` return? (Is the server date and timezone configured as you expect?)

Comment: if server date is suppose  1 day back then same querry CURDATE()-1 also return 0 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Date_Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to make sure both the dates are in same format in your query

EDIT :

`Select * 
From ActivityLookup
where date_Format(addedDateTime, "%Y-%m-%d") = date_Format(Now(), "%Y-%m-%d")`

EDIT 2:

Well I am still not able to understand why you are not getting the expected output, I have created the same table and inserted the similar data and I am getting desired output. PFB the SQL commands I used on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5330a/2).

```
Create table ActivityTypeLookup(activityId int, activitytype varchar(20), activitydescription varchar(200), username varchar(20), addedDateime date);

insert into ActivityTypeLookup values(1, "Activity 1", "sth", "some user", date_Format("2013-02-23", "%y-%m-%d"));
insert into ActivityTypeLookup values(2, "Activity 2", "sth", "some user", date_Format("2013-06-23", "%y-%m-%d"));                               
insert into ActivityTypeLookup values(3, "Activity 1", "sth", "some user", date_Format("2013-06-28", "%y-%m-%d")); 

Select * from ActivityTypeLookup 
where 
date_format(addedDateime, "%Y-%m-%d") = date_format(Now(), "%Y-%m-%d");
```

Comment: can you please edit in my code i am not getting i want for the above given format which is stored in table

Comment: Well I am not sure why you are not getting the output, can u add the output of the table like `select * from activityTypelookup`.

Comment: added output in question please check it

Comment: you can view my second EDIT, and I m not facing any issue on sqlfiddle.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `date()` function to filter the date as according to you

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',time()); //it will give to you current date with same format

SELECT * 
FROM `ActivityTypeLookup` 
WHERE AddedDateTime='$date'
```

Comment: Where do you see OP mentioning PHP?